# ATL_DRAWINFO.prcBounds values are wrong when the C# container having ATL OCX is closed and opened

Tags: c#, atl, ocx

I am placing a ATL OCX control on C# container and decreasing the size of the ATL OCX Control.Then i am closing the C# container.Now i set some property which is responsible to increase or decrease the size of OCX control(this is possible because i am using Multi document Interface, even though i close the container i can set the property for the OCX present on the container).
After this i open the previously closed container, now the OCX calculates the proper width and height of itself according to previously set property and the fires the change to the container. But still in ondraw i m not getting the newly calculated height and width of the OCX. I am getting the old values which are there before closing the container. If i check the variable m_rcPos which contains the RECT of the container it is upto date. But still i m getting old values form the container i.e in ATL_DRAWINFO.prcBounds.

Please somebody out there help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for response. I do not have container code. I can only say that the container is C# container. The problem i am facing is when i reopen the container which is having my activex control. I am getting wrong RECT values in ondraw function.As of my knowledge, if i reopen the container the OCX on the container is created.During the creation i calculating the proper RECT my OCX and i am firing this change to the container.But still in Ondraw i am the old rect values which were there before closing the container